ASP. NET Core Web API project did not generate the request header "Authorization" into the "swagger. json" document file
The ASP. NET Core Web API project did not generate the request header "Authorization" into the "swagger. json" document file
tried to output the request header "Authorization" to the "swagger.json" file
Project Info:

Project: ASP.NET Core Web API
Framework: .NET 8.0



No error output

I am certain that I have enabled document generation in "MyProject. csproj":
True

And by cleaning up the solution and rebuilding and launching the application, you can see that the "MyProject.xml" file has been output.

Open the "MyProject.xml" file and i can see that the request header information has been generated:
 
         
         GetUserInfo
         
         Token
         ResponseModel
     

Visit“ https://localhost:12345/swagger/v1/swagger.json ”I did not see the request header "Authorization" being generated into the "swagger. json" file:



This is my "Program. cs" code:
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
{
swagger.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyProject", Version = "1.0.1" });

swagger.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyProject", Version = "2.0" });

// Include xml file
swagger.IncludeXmlComments(AppContext.BaseDirectory + Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + ".xml", true);

swagger.AddSecurityDefinition(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new()
{
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
    Description = "Bearer Token",
    Name = "Authorization",
    BearerFormat = "JWT",
    Scheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
});

swagger.AddSecurityRequirement(new()
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference()
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
            }
        },
        new string[]{ }
    }
});
});
// Other Code...
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(swagger =>
{
    swagger.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    swagger.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "v2");
});
}
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<IdentityAuthenticationMiddleware>();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

This is my controller code:
/// <summary>
/// UserInfo
/// </summary>
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[Authorize(Roles = "User,Admin")]
public class UserInfoController(HttpRequestModel httpRequestModel) : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly HttpRequestModel _httpRequest = httpRequestModel;

    /// <summary>
    /// GetUserInfo
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authorization">Token</param>
    /// <returns>ResponseModel</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public ResponseModel GetUserInfo([Required][FromHeader(Name = "Authorization")] string authorization)
    {
        using (UserInfoBll userInfoBll = new())
        {
            return userInfoBll.GetUserInfoModel(_httpRequest.Token.UserId);
        }
    }
}


Do u use UseAuthentication  and UseAuthorization? You need to place UseAuthentication() before UseAuthorization(). You attribute Authorize is not working otherwise.

Yes, that's what I did, but the result is still the same:

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<IdentityAuthenticationMiddleware>();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


I found the answer in the official Swagger documentation, and it turns out that these parameter names are not allowed to be used:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/

